# How to change the behaviour of unique true in django model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here I am not deleting the model objects from database. I am just changing the `is_deleted` status to True while delete. But while doing this `unique=True` gives error for the deleted objects so how can I handle this ?

I want to exclude `is_deleted=True` objects from unique True.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


#views
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        object = self.get_object()
        object.is_deleted = True
        object.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [`UniqueConstraint` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) with a condition instead of the `unique` kwarg on the field. Although there is a caveat that validation (by forms etc.) will not be done automatically for a unique constraint with a condition and you will need to do that yourself.

```
from django.db.models import Q


class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name'], condition=Q(is_deleted=False), name='unique_undeleted_name')
        ]
```

**Note**: Since Django 4.1 validation is automatically performed for all constraints using the [`Model.validate_constraints` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_constraints) and hence the above mentioned caveat doesn't apply.

Comment: LOL: we answered almost exactly the same within minutes :p

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes ;) Deja vu, happened some days ago also if I remember correctly.

Comment: thanks. To show validation message instead of throwing error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_name_undelete"` should I have to write new `validate_name` function in my serializer now ?

Comment: @D_P yes you will need to add a `validate_name` method to your serializer to validate this yourself as unfortunately the models built in validation does not handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can work with [*Django's constraint API*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/), you can then specify a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) that has a condition:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    #            no unique=True ↓
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['name'],
                name='unique_name_not_deleted',
                condition=Q(is_deleted=False)
            )
        ]
```

It is of course the database that enforces this, and thus some databases might not have implemented that feature.

Comment: thanks. To show validation message instead of throwing error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_name_undelete"` should I have to write new `validate_name` function in my serializer now ?

Answer (score -1):

You may use following also:

```
class Meta:
       unique_together = ("name", "is_deleted")
```